# LeafletJS: How to remove the zoom control

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, mapbox

I'm trying to remove the zoom controls (+/-) on a [LeafletJS](http://leafletjs.com) map.

I'm using the [MapBox.js version of Leaflet](http://mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.0.2/) but most of the operations are the same as Leaflet. I implement my map like this:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map');

var layer = L.mapbox.tileLayer('MAPBOX-ID', {
    format: 'jpg70',
    minZoom: 13,
    maxZoom: 15,
    reuseTiles: true, 
    unloadInvisibleTiles: true
});
map.addLayer(layer);
map.setView([40.73547,-73.987856]);
```

The [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-zoom) says there's a `zoomControl` option, that will remove the zoom control from the map but I've had no luck in getting it to work.

How can I remove the zoom control with this implementation?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
var map = new L.map('map', { zoomControl: false });
```

With mapbox try:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', { zoomControl: false });
```

See [map creation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-factory) and the [zoomControl option](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-zoomcontrol) in the Leaflet documentation.

Comment: `var map = L.mapbox.map('map', { zoomControl:false });` does not work, the second parameter needs to be a string specifying the map type, the third parameter takes the `{ zoomControl:false }`

Comment: for those just wanting to disable the mousewheel zoom, but not disable the ability to zoom using the + and - buttons on the map, substitute `zoomControl` with `scrollWheelZoom`

Answer (score 71):

If you want to dynamically turn on and off zooming you can do something like this:

```
map.touchZoom.disable();
map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
map.boxZoom.disable();
map.keyboard.disable();
$(".leaflet-control-zoom").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

Comment: For those who want to disable drag feature, you can do this too: map.dragging.disable();

Answer (score 17):

Thanks to coordinate's answer I was able to figure out the correct method. The solution is:

```
// Create the map
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', null, { zoomControl:false });

// Create my custom layer
var layer = L.mapbox.tileLayer('MAPBOX-ID', {
    format: 'jpg80',
    minZoom: 13,
    maxZoom:15,
    tileSize: 256,
    reuseTiles: true, 
    unloadInvisibleTiles: true
});


// Add the layer
map.addLayer(layer);
```

Answer (score 17):

you can remove the control `zoomControl` in this way:

```
map.removeControl(map.zoomControl);
```

Answer (score 10):

You can just use

`map.zoomControl.remove();`

Comment: in my case a get a TypeError: map.zoomControl.remove is not a function. The way I found is using the `removeControl` function like this: `map.removeControl(map.zoomControl);`

Comment: I guess, map.zoomControl.remove() is a new function in version 1.0.0 while map.removeControl() is for lower versions.

Answer (score 7):

```
map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
```

Answer (score 6):

To dynamically remove then add back the zoom control:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map');

if( wantToRemove ) {
    map.removeControl( map.zoomControl ); 
} else {
    map.addControl( map.zoomControl );
}
```

Comment: This answer is still working, unlike the others