# How to remove zoom in and out on leaflet map leaving gps icon

Tags: css, search, gps, maps, leaflet

[image]

---

I want to display zoom in and out icons (controls) when on desktop and to display gps icon only when browsing on mobile.
I'm using this css https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.1.0/dist/leaflet.css 
when I disable controls in css all control icons disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the HTML class of the zoom thing is `.leaflet-zoom-box`, and you don't have much knowledge of CSS and HTML,

a very basic fix is to add this into the `.leaflet-zoom-box` part of the CSS:

```
.leaflet-zoom-box {
    display: none;
}
```

That basically makes it not appear, but it can still be clicked on.

To truly remove it, go into the HTML file which holds the code, look for the `div` or whatever container the `.leaflet-zoom-box` is housed in, and remove all of that code.

Caution though, doing that may destroy the alignment of other items on the page, so always back it up first before attempting it.

Hope I helped!

Comment: thanks for helping  .leaflet-zoom-box  doesn't  work        .leaflet-control {display:none;}works but  even the GPS icon doesn't display

Comment: Can you edit your question and post in all the HTML that you have? I'll take a look and see what I can do

Comment: it created with this javascript https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/blob/master/dist/leaflet-search.src.js                                              
 only <div id="map"></div> on html

Comment: I can't help you with this one, I'm very good at HTML and CSS, but I know practically nuts about JS. What I do know however, if you want to remove the zoom, it's going to be complicated. JavaScript code easily breaks when some things are not "found". If something is not declared (if you remove the zoom), and there are some actions regarding the zoom, it will not work, and may even break the whole code, or the rest of it after whatever is affected.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16537572/7179235) there is an option for this:

`var map = new L.Map('map', { zoomControl:false });`